# Variable function calling in Python

Tags: python, call

Let `Instrument` be a class with three functions `piano(self)`, `guitar(self)` and `trumpet(self)`. The class has also a `play(self)` function, which will call the proper method, according to the instrument that is represented in the class.

**Is there a way, with only one class `Instrument` (i.e., no other abstract class), to define the method that should be invoked when calling the `play` method?**

In other words, is there a way to do the following:

```
my_piano = Instrument(piano)
my_piano.play() # calls piano(self) method

my_guitar = Instrument(guitar)
my_guitar.play() # calls guitar(self) method

my_trumpet = Instrument(trumpet)
my_trumpet.play() # calls trumpet(self) method
```

A rather simple way of doing it, but not very code clean, is to put a variable in the constructor, and then put a lot of conditions in the `play` method, like this:

```
def Instrument(object):
    def __init__(self, instrument_type):
        self.instrument_type = instrument_type

    def play(self):
        if instrument_type == 0:
            self.piano()
        elif instrument_type == 1:
            self.guitar()
        elif instrument_type == 2:
            self.trumpet()
```

The proper way of doing it would be to have an `Instrument`class and then three `Piano`, `Guitar` and `Trumpet` classes which inherit from `Instrument`. But for the need I have, that would be complicate things for not much.

**EDIT**

As requested, I explain my actual problem, which is almost identical. 
I have a class `ComputeSth` that can use five different methods to compute that something. It can compute it in ways `a(self)`, `b(self)`, ..., `f(self)`.
For exampple, sometimes I want to compute according to `a`, some other times according to `c`. That is easy if I just do:

```
my_computer = ComputeSth()
my_computer.a()
my_computer.c()
```

But then I noticed that in order to easily use this class in other parts of my code, I would prefer to do `my_computer.compute()`. So, I thought it would be convenient to construct the instance with the actual method to compute when calling `compute(self)`. I didn't want to write five other classes, since they really wouldn't represent five different objects, but rather five ways of doing the same. I can't pass the function `a`,...,`f` as an input of the constructor because the require the `self`.
In other words, same as the example with `Instrument`, but with less "real world inheritance".

Comment: This is what polymorphism, in any object oriented language is for. You are supposed to create separate classes for Piano/Guitar which inherit from base class Instrument

Comment: You could look into [single dispatch](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) but I'm not 100% sure it works on methods and I believe it would be more of a hassle than just playing with inheritance.

Comment: @lejlot Yes, I know that I can do it like you propose on your answer (see my last paragraph). Buy I thought that maybe there could be a simpler way, like the one I propose which is ugly but simple and works. In the instrument example it makes far more logic to do it with inheritance, but in my actual problem it will look heavy and more complicated that I want.

Comment: then you should describe your actual problem, because otherwise we cannot give you any reasonable answer.

Comment: You're going to have to post something closer to your real problem if you want a useful solution. As it is, there's no reason not to use subclasses.

Comment: @lejlot @chepner See edit. It is almost identical problem, but I prefered to write it with the `Instrument` because it was easier to understand.

Comment: This is actually still "way to go" with inheritance, as these are different types of computing. In python, with multiple inheritance and "mixins" it is ok to have a subclass with just one method

Comment: @lejlot Ok then. I think I had this idea of not using subclasses unless it was strictly necessary (in both real world logics and code logic). But now I notice that the solution will be even more complicated (or ugly) if I don't do inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what polymorphism is for

```
class Instrument:

  def play(self):
    pass

class Guitar(Instrument):

  def play(self):
    print 'brau dau'

class Drum(Instrument):

  def play(self):
    print 'dum dum'


guitar = Guitar()
guitar.play()

drum = Drum()
drum.play()
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Also `Instrument.play` should [`raise NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError)

Answer (score 3):

This is most certainly the wrong design, but definitely doable:

```
class Instrument:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def play(self):
        self.method(self)

    def piano(self):
        print("I am a piano")

    def trumpet(self):
        print("I am a trumpet")

    def guitar(self):
        print("I am a guitar")

piano = Instrument.piano
trumpet = Instrument.trumpet
guitar = Instrument.guitar

my_piano = Instrument(piano)
my_piano.play()
#... and others
```

You pass an unbound class method to the `__init__` of instrument, and then in `play` invoke that method on `self`.

You could even extend the available instruments by creating freestanding functions

```
def violin(self):
    print("I am playing a violin")

my_violin = Instrument(violin)
my_violin.play()
```

But the whole approach shown above does have very little use in the python world.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to make a class hierarchy, you could define all possible types in an `enum` class, and then just choose correct method. In order to avoid `if` statements you may use dictionaries:

```
In [1]: import enum

In [2]: class InstrumentType(enum.Enum):
   ...:     PIANO = 0
   ...:     GUITAR = 1
   ...:     TRUMPET = 2
   ...:     

In [3]: class Instrument:
   ...:     def __init__(self, type):
   ...:         self.type = type
   ...:     def piano(self):
   ...:         print('Piano')
   ...:     def guitar(self):
   ...:         print('Guitar')
   ...:     def trumpet(self):
   ...:         print('Trumpet')
   ...:     def play(self):
   ...:         return {
   ...:             InstrumentType.PIANO: self.piano,
   ...:             InstrumentType.GUITAR: self.guitar,
   ...:             InstrumentType.TRUMPET: self.trumpet
   ...:         }.get(self.type, lambda: print('Not an instrument'))()
   ...:     

In [4]: guitar = Instrument(InstrumentType.GUITAR)

In [5]: guitar.play()
Guitar

In [6]: unknown = Instrument('UNKNOWN')

In [7]: unknown.play()
Not an instrument
```